# Can a multiprocessing.Pipe() be flushed in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to coding. As per my understanding after closing the pipe, it cannot be accessed and so the items present in the pipe. However, I want to flush all the items present in the pipe before closing it. Is it possible?

```
import multiprocessing

def child(r, w):
    r.close()
    for n in range(11):
        w.send(n)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    r, w = multiprocessing.Pipe()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=child, args=(r, w))
    p.start()
    w.close()
    print("Item received by main:", r.recv())
    #flush
    if r.poll():
        print("Item still left on pipe:", r.recv())
    p.join()
```